# Dealing with boxes and trait objects

Tags: rust

I have a vector of boxes of some trait `core::Object` objects:

```
pub struct Packfile<'a> {
    pub version: u32,
    pub objects: Vec<Box<core::Object + 'a>>,
    ...
```

Now, I want one method of `Packfile` to return one of those objects optionally: `-> Option<Box<core::Object + 'a>>`. So, having `i` as a reference to the index I want, I return this:

```
Some(self.objects[*i])
```

OK, this doesn't work because I'm moving the box outside of the vec. Makes sense. Let's `clone` it (`core::Object` inherits from `Clone`).

```
Some(self.objects[*i].clone())
```

Now, here is what I don't understand. `self.objects[*i]` is a box, and `clone()` on boxes [do this](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.clone): `impl<T> Clone for Box<T> where T: Clone { fn clone(&self) -> Box<T>; }` so `clone()` should be giving me a box, right? But I get this error:

```
src/packfile/mod.rs:190:20: 190:44 error: mismatched types:
 expected `Box<core::Object + 'a>`,
    found `core::Object + 'a`
(expected box,
    found trait core::Object)
src/packfile/mod.rs:190             Some(self.objects[*i].clone()),
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I don't get why I'm getting a `T` and not a `Box<T>` out of `clone()`.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine with just a reference to the object, you can do something like:

```
Some(&self.objects[*i])
```

You can even implement [`Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) to be able to leverage the indexing operator, so you can do `some_packfile[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

> So I don't get why I'm getting a T and not a Box out of clone().

Methods *also* do auto deref. I don't know what a `core::Object` is, but if it implements `Clone`, that's why, I'd bet.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what "do auto deref" means? A `core::Object` is just some trait, that yes, it inherits from `Clone`.

Comment: some_box.foo() will call the `foo()` method on what is in the box, not on the box itself. It will do this as many times as it needs to call the inner method, say, if it was wrapped in three boxes.